# Select option in Angular xeditable and Angular Formly

Tags: angularjs, x-editable, angular-formly

I don't know how to give e-ng-options of xeditable in angular Formly.

Here is the formly Config:

```
     formlyConfig.setType({
          extends: 'select',
          template: '<div><span editable-select="model[options.key]" e-ng-options="" e-name="{{::id}}">{{ model[options.key] || "empty" }}</span></div>',
          name: 'editableSelect'
        });
```

Here is the  select value:

```
    {
        className: 'col-xs-12 col-sm-6',
        type: 'editableSelect',
        key: 'gender',
        templateOptions: {
          label: 'Gender',
          options: [
        {name: 'Male', value: 'male'},
        {name: 'Female', value: 'female'}]
        }
     }
```

Pls look at [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/doqorirubo/edit?js,output)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just figured it out.

```
formlyConfig.setType({
      extends: 'select',
      template: '<div><span editable-select="model[options.key]" e-ng-options="s.value as s.name for s in {{options.templateOptions.options}}" e-name="{{::id}}" e-placeholder="{{options.templateOptions.placeholder}}">{{ model[options.key] || "empty" }}</span></div>',
      name: 'editableSelect'
});
```

Refered [xeditable](http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#select-local)